# SpringDataJpa how do I fetch a list of objects each containing another list?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a group chat app using Angular and SpringBoot, I need to write a query that returns me a list of ChatDTO elements, each chatDTO rapresents a chat the logged user took part in, only each chat element has a list of the chat users's id and a list of messages (I'll first get all of the messages then when the query works I'll modify it), only I haven't been able to make it work.

Here's the properties of the ChatDTO object:

```
`private Long id;
 private String nome;
 private Date dataCreazione;
 private ArrayList<Long> utentiIds;
 private List<ChatMessaggioEntity> messaggi;`
```

they are the id, name, creation date, the list of users id and the list of messages.

the mySQL tables are group_chat(id, nome, data_creazione), chat_account(id, fk_chat, fk_account) and chat_messaggio(unimportant_stuff, fk_chat)

I tried this method

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.demo.dto.ChatDTO(gc.id, gc.nome, gc.dataCreazione, " +
               "(SELECT ca.fkAccount FROM ChatAccountEntity ca WHERE ca.fkChat = gc.id), cm) " +
               "FROM GroupChatEntity gc " +
               "JOIN ChatMessaggio cm ON cm.fkChat = gc.id " +
               "WHERE gc.id IN (SELECT ca.fkChat FROM ChatAccountEntity ca WHERE ca.fkAccount = :idAccount)")
        List<ChatDTO> findChatsByAccountId(@Param("idAccount") Long idAccount);
```

but it tells me that it couldn't find an appropriate constructor for the object since it expects the userIds to be a single long instead of a list, same thing for the messages, but if I try and  do that (just out of curiosity) the query fails on execution because "subquery returned more than one record", but I do want it to return more than one record, I want jpa to have that result-set as a list in the ChatDTO object

is there an easy way to do that? I'm trying to get all these informations with a single query to boost performance

Comment: No, as you get a cartesian result from your query. How/when should a new `ChatDTO` been made, when to stop parsing the query for `userids, or nested messages? There is no way to express that in a query expression. The easiest is probably to parse the result yourself and convert to the DTO.